# Different dharmas of different aspects of our existence

Tags: scripture, identification-request

I heard something like below

> Hunger, thirst, increasing, decreasing, etc., are the dharmas of the
> body. Sad, happy, etc., are the dharmas of manas........................

I didn't remember the whole list of all aspects and their dharmas. Where can I find them?

Comment: Maybe in Shrimad Bhagvatam. The closest thing I could find: (it's in hindi although) https://www.bhaskar.com/news/MP-OTH-MAT-latest-ganjbasoda-news-033503-21022-NOR.html

Answer (score 2):

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/index.htm

Some aspects are found in Shanti Parva and some in Anushasana Parva.

Link to Anushasana Parva.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find them?

The word "dharma" has many meanings. The most common meaning, and the meaning that people think of when they hear the word, is "morality". But dharma has other meanings like nature, property, quality, etc:

> धर्म  m.  dharma  attribute
>
> धर्म  m.  dharma  nature
>
> धर्म  m.  dharma  manner
>
> From Spokensanskrit.org

"Dharma" in this context you cited just means "property". So, hunger, thirst, etc. are all properties (dharmas) of the body, whereas happiness, sadness, etc. are properties of the mind since they are emotions.

Comment: OP is asking  about all the similar aspects like body, mind ....etc what is the other? I believe he didn't ask abt what dharma meant here?

Comment: I believe you can extend annamaya Kosha manomaya kosha vignaanamaya kosha ...etc

Comment: Yeah @PrasannaR